# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'category'. Check that 'api.category.apps.CategoryConfig.name' is correct

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using `Django 3.2`, and `Django REST Framework`. Main project name is `ECOM` and `api` is app. Inside `api` there are multiple apps like category, migrations, order, payment, product, user. Now I want to inform `ecom.settings` about installed `api`. HOW I should do it ?

`settings.py` of `ECOM` :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     #other basic install
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'api',
    'api.category',
]
```

but getting error.

My category `apps.py` file looks like

```
class CategoryConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'category'
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari yes bro problem solved thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to change `name` in your category `apps.py` like this

```
class CategoryConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'api.category'
```

Answer (score 3):

**AppConfig.name** is a full python path to the application.
in your case  your app category is inside another app called api so try to change your apps.py file to this :

```
class CategoryConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'api.category' // full path to your app category
```

the source from django  documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.name

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make `api` directory a package by creating a `__init__.py` file in it. Then instead of adding just `api` in `INSTALLED_APPS` list just add `api.category`.

Like this -

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     #other basic install
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'api.category',
]
```